# use 'useEffect' hook to run code only once by passing an empty array as the 2nd parameter, however ESLint complains the empty array

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am developing a react-native project on Visual Studio Code IDE.

For some reason, my Visual Studio Code starts to automatically fill code to solve lint errors.

For example, I use `useEffect` hook to run some code only once (so I need to pass an empty array as the 2nd parameter of `useEffect`). Code is like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
     ...
      // imaging my code here has 'foo', 'bar', etc variables
     ...
     ...
    return () => {
      console.log('Screen did unmount');
    };
  }, []); // ESLint complains the empty array.
```

The ESLint complains that empty array like immediately after I typed above code:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'foo', 'bar'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

If I now ctrl+s to save my code. Visual Studio automatically adding code to the empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
     ...
      // imaging my code here has 'foo', 'bar', etc variables
     ...
     ...
    return () => {
      console.log('Screen did unmount');
    };
  }, [foo, bar]);
```

My two questions:

1. According to the way how the `useEffect` hook works, in order to run the code only once, I have to pass an empty array. Why ESLint complains about that? What is the right way to have the code inside `useEffect` to only run once if mine is not recommended?
2. How to make my Visual Studio Code stop automatically adding code to resolve ESLint error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two methods for this.

You can use `// eslint-disable-next-line` in your code

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
    // imaging my code here has 'foo', 'bar', etc variables
    ...
    ...
    return () => {
        console.log('Screen did unmount');
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```

Or you can remove edit the settings of eslint of Visual Studio code.

[Visual Studio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qKes.png)

Cheers.

Comment: Are you saying passing the empty array is the correct way to make sure the code run only once & it is ESLint's problem that it complains the empty array? I mean I would like my two questions be answered clearly. Thanks!